# How do I translate a sentence asking about travel plans?

Tags: translation

How do I translate:

“May I know when Max will return to Korea? And which flight?” Please keep Max in English.

Google Translate does not seem to translate this correctly.

Comment: Why do you think google translate is wrong? Could you please post your attempt so people can help correct it?

Comment: I am a bit surprised that no one asked whether the speaker is in Korea. As for Google Translate, I have found that it generates a translation erroneous in some ways.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would say the first sentence:

> Max가 언제 한국으로 돌아갈 지 알려 줄 수 있어요?

There are dozens of slight variants on this sentence.

To ask what the flight number is, you can say

> 항공편 번호는 뭐요?

All of these translations will depend a great deal on who you are speaking to. Level of speech is very important in Korean. I have translated the sentences into 해요체, which is the informal but polite speech level.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions below are used when you are talking in a formal situation, or talking to a stranger or an older person. Although they are slightly different, all of them would convey the same message to the person you are talking to.

> Max는 언제 한국으로 돌아가죠? (When will Max return?).
>
> Max가 언제 한국으로 돌아가는지 알 수 있을까요?(May I know when will Max return?).
>
> Max가 언제 한국으로 돌아가는지 알려주실 수 있으세요? (Could you tell me when will Max return?)

If you are talking to a person younger than you, you may say:

> Max 한국에 언제 돌아간대?

And which flight? could be simply translate as:

> 어떤 항공으로? (Airline), 어떤 항공편으로? (Flight number)